# OptionParser.parse_args() shows error "no such option : --mode" with no changes in the Python environment

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code here :

```
from optparse import OptionParser
parser = OptionParser(description="Retrieve reference data.")
parser.add_option("-a","--ip",dest="host",help="server name or IP (default: %default)",metavar="ipAddress",default="localhost")
parser.add_option("-p",dest="port",type="int",help="server port (default: %default)",metavar="tcpPort",default=8194)
```

Usually this works without an issue, however, since about a week this throws this error :

Usage: pydevconsole.py [options]
pydevconsole.py: error: no such option: --mode

Googling this did not help at all. What seems to be the issue here ?

I tried googling it but since I do not use optparse before it's very challenging.